How can I safeguard my GitHub token in the workflow and deploy it using Docker for spring cloud config?
How do you secure your github token when deploying your spring cloud config server password on docker using github workflow and keep your repository public while development
  build_config_server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "17"
          distribution: "temurin"
          cache: maven
      - name: Build Maven Config Service
        run: mvn -B package --file config-server/pom.xml
      - name: Build docker Config Service
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/app-config-server:latest -f config-server/Dockerfile config-server
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Set Git Token as an environment variable
        run: echo "SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/app-config-server:latest


This was one of the problems why I don't keep my repositories public until development completes. I develop services using microservice architecture where I use config server which contains git password it won't be problem creating env variable and keeping it public but will cause problem when CI/CD.

name: Java CI/CD with Maven and Docker on config-server

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
    paths:
      - "config-server/**"
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  build_config_server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "17"
          distribution: "temurin"
          cache: maven
      - name: Build Maven Config Service
        run: mvn -B package --file config-server/pom.xml
      - name: Build docker Config Service
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/app-config-server:latest -f config-server/Dockerfile --build-arg SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GITHUB_PASSWORD="${{ secrets.CONFIG_PASSWORD }}" config-server
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/app-config-server:latest

FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR usr/src
ARG SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GITHUB_PASSWORD
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD=$SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GITHUB_PASSWORD
ADD /target/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar", "config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

